# How can I visualize training accuracy at each iteration in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

Is there any possible way to plot the training accuracy at each iteration in Keras?

I mean something similar to the following [plot from MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/trainingoptions.html):

[image]

Comment: You can use tensorboard callbacks for monitoring: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard?version=stable

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I need to plot the training accuracy at each **iteration** not epoch!

Comment: yes, you mean `at each batch`, that's exactly what is it for.

Comment: set batch_size to 1 :D

Comment: @YOLO I only added update_freq='batch' to TensorBoard(), and I've got this warning "RuntimeWarning: Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (0.465966). Check your callbacks. % (hook_name, delta_t_median), RuntimeWarning)" and my model not learning anymore!

Comment: what version of keras are you using ?

Comment: @YOLO Keras 2.3.1, and Python 3.6.8